# Getting a value from a label at POST

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

There's a place into my screen that I populate a label with a specific string value after some interaction with my user during the runtime. I use javascript for that.

Is there anyway to get the value of this lavel with my controller after its `POST` method is activated ?

Thanks, guys !

Answer (score 3):

### Option #1

Put the value in an HTML `<input>` element with a `name` attribute? Might need to dress down 
the input element, since it will look like a textbox.

### Option #2

Mirror the value in a hidden input `<input type="hidden" value="yourValue" />` inside the form you're posting.

Comment: Option number two is probably the best of the two.

Comment: Since its a POST method, how can I get it into my controller? ´Request´ don't seems to work

Comment: You're using MVC--don't use `Request` object. At the minimum, use named parameters in your controller. Ideally, you should use a strongly typed view model. Give us some controller code you have now, and we can probably help more :)